# How to make JS HTMLElement.click() work on file input in Vue 3 in Chrome?

Tags: javascript, vue.js, google-chrome

I'm trying to build a basic file upload feature in my Vue 3 app.

I have a basic HTML :

```
<button @click="pickFile" class="btn btn-primary">
    <i class="fas fa-file-import"></i>
    <span>Importer un fichier</span>
</button>
<input
    type="file"
    style="display: none;"
    ref="fileInput"
    @change="onFilePicked" 
/>
```

and some methods :

```
methods: {
    pickFile() {
        this.$refs.fileInput.click();
    },

    onFilePicked() {
        console.log("file picked");
    }
}
```

The file input is hidden and my expected behaviour is that when the user clicks the button, the browser would open a file picker window.

My code above works like expected in Firefox and Safari but not in Chrome.

Now I've seen [VueJS: trigger input file from button](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39577189/vuejs-trigger-input-file-from-button) but the answers don't seem to work for Vue 3. I've also seen this Github issue https://github.com/vuejs/vue/issues/7028 but it doesn't really give me any clue as how to fix it.

Any ideas how I could fix that?

Comment: What I would do is change the button to a `<label for="someid">` with all the stylings you want, then add `id="someid"` to the `input` see if that solves the issue

Comment: oddly - your code works fine in Chrome for me

Comment: @JaromandaX wasn't working like I said but rebooted my computer and now it does, strange. Thanks for your answer

Comment: yeah, that is odd!! Perhaps a (very recent) chrome update?