# Bind B-Button with input file / BootstrapVue

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs2, bootstrap-vue

I try to have a input file button (this is in a v-for loop). But I don't want to use the `b-form-file` tag.

So I've tried - at least - all things I have seen, but nothing worked out for me.

I have the following code:

```
<b-button @click="selectFile()" variant="success" :id="index"> Upload </b-button>
<input type="file" ref="file" style="display: none;"/>
```

and this in my script / methods:

```
methods: {
  selectFile() {
    this.$refs.file;
  }
}
```

Result: When I click the button nothing happend - but I get no error as well.

Thanks for your help !

Answer (score 0):

Instead of using a button, you should use a `<label>` instead with the `for` attribute. You can then use CSS to style the label to look like a button.

```html
<label for="file" class="btn btn-success"> Upload </label>
<input id="file" type="file" style="display: none;" />
```

Since you're using it in a `v-for` you will need to generate dynamic ID's for your input. For this you could either use a unique identifier if your items have one, or you could use the `index`.

```html
<div v-for="(item, index) in items">
  <label :for="`file-${index}`" class="btn btn-success"> Upload </label>
  <input :id="`file-${index}`" type="file" style="display: none;"/>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

In **Vue** with **BootstrapVue**:

How code below works:

1. Open file explorer on button (label) click;
2. Select a file, continue;
3. @onChange will detect new file:

```html
<label>
  <button/> //this can be an icon, link,...
  <input @change="doSomething" type="file" ref="file" accept="image/gif, 
    image/jpeg, image/png" hidden/>
</label>
```

4. Handle the file

```js
doSomething(e: any) { 
  const file = e.target.files[0]
}
```

[Question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/37535657/16758153) is a duplicate, [my answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/69362717/16758153) tho

Comment: It's fairly bad practice to place interactive content inside a <label>, and it also doesn't work unless the associated input is placed first, meaning the example you've written out doesn't work. At least when i tested on win10, Chrome.

Comment: This works in Vue2 without any problems. Can you tell me something more about the "bad practice"?

Comment: Placings interactive content inside a label is bad for accessibility, and general goes against the HTML spec. Here's the code i tried, which didn't work, [codepen](https://codepen.io/Hiws/pen/abwMdvM). The [spec](https://html.spec.whatwg.org/multipage/forms.html#the-label-element) mentions that if no `for` attribute is used, then the first `labelable element` (button/label) is used.
Which means in your example, clicking the label activates the button, not the input, since it's first. Also mentioned [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/label#interactive_content)