# trigger b-form-file after clicking on b-button

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs2, bootstrap-vue

I'm working with `BootstrapVue` and I want to trigger my `b-form-file` after clicking on my `b-button`, because of style cases. I also want to have the `b-form-file` hidden it shouldn't been seen anywhere.

I've tried to do it like following but this doesn't work out for me..

```
<b-button variant="danger" @click="$refs.upload.click()">Upload</b-button>

<b-form-file ref="upload"></b-form-file>
```

Please let me know if you have any idea how I can fix that! Thank You!

**-> I want to advoid jQuery code and I can't use base HTML `input` - I need `b-form-file`**

Comment: Haven't you already asked this exact questions once before? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69359354/bind-b-button-with-input-file-bootstrapvue/69361433#69361433

Comment: Refer to this page https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39577189/vuejs-trigger-input-file-from-button

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You must required to make a method for click on  for example:

```
<b-button variant="danger" @click="open">Upload</b-button>
<b-form-file id="upload"></b-form-file>

<script>
     export default {
          methods: {
            open: ()=> {document.getElementById('upload').click()},
          }
     }
</script>
```

Comment: Thanks - after finding my mistake in my code, your answer worked out well! :)

Comment: Welcome Sir! :)

Answer (score 0):

```
<b-form-file 
    ref="signatureFile" 
    @input="validate(signature)" 
    accept=".jpeg, .jpg, .png"
    v-model="signature" 
    class="d-none" 
    plain
></b-form-file>

<b-button  
    @click="$refs.signatureFile.$el.click();" 
    variant="tertiary"
>
    {{ Signature ? Signature.name : 'Choose File' }}
</b-button>
```